# OnTouchListener prevents map from moving

Tags: android, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I am using google maps API and I have some code that tries to capture the position of the center of the map after the user has dragged it.

```
MapView mv = ...;

mv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            GeoPoint pt = mv.getMapCenter();
            //do something with the point
            return A;
        }
        return B;
    }
});
```

Now my problem is with the return values:

- if B is false, the map gets dragged but I only see the `ACTION_DOWN` event and `ACTION_UP` is never triggered - which I understand
- if B is true, I receive the `ACTION_UP` event, but the map is not dragged
- it seems that whether A is true or false does not make a difference

What I want is to receive the `ACTION_UP` event AND to have the map dragged.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I had a similar issue with handling touches on mapview markers, if onTouchEvent returned true the map wouldnt ever move, when i coded the listener to return true ONLY when the event did get caught (To make the markers draggable) the map worked exactly as intended.

Comment: @Drknezz on a drag move, you get one `ACTION_DOWN` event, then several `ACTION_MOVE` events and finally an `ACTION_UP` event. If I return true, map does not nove, if I return false, I only see `ACTION_DOWN` but not the next events...

Comment: Maybe return a call to MapView.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)? That way your calls wouldn't interer with the stock behaviour and you'd be able to catch ACTION_UP's to calculate the center of the map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution: Instead of using the default MapView, use a custom MapView which has a GestureDetector, basically, this lets you create a custom event listener for your map which helps you avoid the issue of messing up the dragging etc. and moreover gives you are vast number of interaction options compared to the default MapView. A couple of months ago I'd faced a similar problem and so I decided to implement the solution I just mentioned. Here's the code for the custom MapView called TapControlledMapView and the code for the interface for the custom listener is provided at the bottom : http://pastebin.com/kUrm9zFg.

So to implement the listener, all you need to do is use the following code in your mapactivity class (Oh and in case you didn't know this, you have to declare the following in your MapActivity layout XML file since you are using a custom MapView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
//The bottom line was the tricky business (You get ClassCastExceptions and whatnot)
<NAMEOFYOURPROJECT.TapControlledMapView (ex: com.android.googlemapsapp.TapControlledMapView)
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="API_KEY_HERE"
/>
```

and use the following code in your MapActivity class.

```
mapView.setOnSingleTapListener(new OnSingleTapListener() {

@Override
 public boolean onSingleTap(MotionEvent arg1) {
 if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
 {
  GeoPoint pt = mv.getMapCenter();
  // do something with the point.
  return ***true***;
 }
return true;
});
```

Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Following @ViswaPatel's idea, I create a new MapView class, extending MapView, which overrides the `onTouchEvent` method and manages its own listeners:

```
public class CustomMapView extends MapView {

    private OnTouchListener lst;

    public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
        super(context, apiKey);
    }

    public void setOnActionUpListener(OnTouchListener lst) {
        this.lst = lst;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        if (lst != null && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            lst.onTouch(this, event); // return value ignored
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The calling code is:

```
  mv.setOnActionUpListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final GeoPoint pt = mv.getMapView().getMapCenter();
            //doing my stuff here
            return true; //ignored anyway
        }
    });
}
```